# How to render django form with validators errors ussing reverse() instea of render() to not duplicate the code actually rendering the whole view?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to implement forms with validators for the 1st time. I have learned that to actually display validators errors to user after he/she will send the form, in the view function definition that covers POST request processing I have to once again trigger view rendering and pass all saved form data (I am storing that in `form` variable) to this view.

I could do it like that:

```
if form.is_valid:
   (..)
else:
   return render(request, "auctions/listing-details.html", {"auction_id": auction_id, "bidding_form": form}
```

The problem is, that my view requires bunch of params that are being calculated before render function is being called. So to not have to repeat all the calculation code + render() with all the params, I wanted to use `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse())` - in my understanding that would redirect the app to the GET request processing of the view (that includes all the params calculation needed for the view rendering).

So for example I could do somethig like:

```
if form.is_valid:
   (..)
else:
   return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("auctions:listing_details", kwargs={"auction_id": auction_id, "bidding_form": form},))
```

BUT with this approach I am getting error `Reverse for 'listing_details' with keyword arguments '{'auction_id': 3, 'bidding_form': <BidForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(bid_amount)>}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['listing\\-details/(?P<auction_id>[0-9]+)\\Z']`

Why is that? Is the only approach is to use render() with moving all needed params calculation above the POST/GET conditions in my view function (so they could be shared) but still have to duplicate whole render() call with all the required params in both form.is_valid() and else cases?